# Build java project with parameters using maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to build a Java project using Maven *with parameters*, which change in every build. One parameter is for example a key which is checked inside of the program.

The parameters should not be able to be read out once the project is build. Tried different Approche including plugins from org.codehaus.mojo… but having problems "plugin execution not covered by lifecycle"....

```
    /****************************/
    /**read property values     */
    /****************************/
    //Create a new property list
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //create a input strem
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    //try to read the property file
    try {
        String filename ="restApi.properties";
        inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if(inputStream==null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read required properties");
        }
        properties.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("property_mainUrlValue"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

my pom.xml

```
<properties>        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <property_mainUrlValue>property_mainUrlValue</property_mainUrlValue>
<properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/restApi.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

[error shown in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdqr2.png)

```
     Unable to read required properties
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at itAsset.Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

Comment: Why are parameters changing for each build? What kind of parameters are you talking? And for what purpose are they used?

Comment: thought about to build a jar for a IOT device...appkey and url and thingName would be provided by the build sever...through installation routine i would transfer the program afterwards to the thing...

Comment: generic iot parameters such as mac &&& are checked during execution. Therefore the program would only work on that specific device..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are searching for what Maven calls (for some reason which I do not understand) "**filtering**".

The basic idea is this:

You turn on the feature by including the following configuration into `pom.xml`:

```
...
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
...
```

This causes that when you run `mvn resources:resources -Dkey="mmm123"`, and you have a resource `src/main/resources/restApi.properties` containing line

```
appKey=${key}
```

then Maven will create a resource output in `target/classes/restApi.properties` which contains

```
appKey=mmm123
```

The detailed description is here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html